# Eclipse: Update Memory Monitor or Memory Browser Address

Tags: eclipse, debugging, memory, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse Stand-Alone Debugger to examine an applications Stack. My problem is the `Memory Monitor` and `Memory Browser` don't update the Address which they inspect memory at while stepping through disassembly instructions.

I've entered `$esp` as an expression, both in Memory Browser als well as Memory Monitor, to inspect memory at the current Stack Pointer. I expected Eclipse to update the address (interpret the expression) after every step in the debugger. Since it may (or is even likely to) change.

But after a push instruction (which decreases the value in `$esp` by 4), neither memory inspector views memory at the "new" current `ESP`. I have to manually click "Go" next to Memory Browser's address field, or (even worse) delete the "old" Memory Monitor and set up a new one.

Is there a way to always inspect memory at the current `ESP` address?

I'm running Linux, Eclipse Luna, using the Stand-alone debugger script from Eclipse CDT:

`/usr/lib/eclipse-cdt/plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.debug.application_1.1.0.201502131403/scripts/cdtdebug.sh`

BTW I hoped to get help at the official Eclipse forums, but the thread I posted hasn't been made public since yesterday :(

Comment: Re forum post, I think you will have to wait for a weekday as most likely the most active users who could approve your post are enjoying a nice weekend away from their computers (unlike me!)

Comment: So... You're telling me there are people who enjoy to be away from their computers? Not exactly my definition of a tech community, lol!